# Is this absolute value notation or something else?

Tags: notation, absolute-value

In [this document](http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/levmar.pdf), in Figure 1 (second to last page) there are several uses of $\| \;\;\|$:

[image]

Is this another notation for absolute value, or is this a notation for something to do with vectors/matrices?

Comment: that is a "norm" a generalization of absolute value. In simplest term norm of a vector is its length. [ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the document says *immediately following the introduction*:

[image]

[This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Definition) has the definition of the $2$-norm and the $\infty$-norm of a vector. The definition is as follows: for a vector $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\in\mathbb{R}^m$, the $p$-norm of $x$ is
$$\|x\|_p:=(x_1^p+\cdots+x_m^p)^{1/p}$$
if $p$ is finite, and if $p=\infty$, we define
$$\|x\|_\infty:=\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}.$$